# Add value of div attribute into INPUT

Tags: jquery

Struggling with adding values of divs' attributes into inputs:

My HTML is:

```
  <div class="modal-body" client-name="test1">
      <input class="gform_hidden"/>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body" client-name="new name">
      <input class="gform_hidden"/>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body" client-name="test3">
      <input class="gform_hidden"/>
  </div>
```

And the jQuery code:

```
  $('.modal-body').each(function () {
     var cname = $(this).attr('client-name');
     $('input.gform_hidden').val(cname);
 });
```

Can any one help me to get individual value but not the last one.

Please see the jsfiddle below: http://jsfiddle.net/9nph7eyc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use current context `this` along with find selector to find input element in it:

```
 $('.modal-body').each(function () {
     $(this).find('input').val($(this).attr('client-name'));
 });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f92nazm6/)**

Answer (score 1):

For each input field you need to pass the value of its parent element's `client-name` attribute value

```
$('.modal-body input.gform_hidden').val(function () {
    return $(this).parent().attr('client-name')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pec3dc02/)

In your code the problem is `$('input.gform_hidden').val(cname);`, where in every iteration you are changing the value of all the input elements instead of targeting only one input, so at the end of the loop all input elements will have the value of the last iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should amend your HTML to use `data-*` attributes to store custom information. Creating your own attributes as you are can cause JS and/or UI issues:

```
<div class="modal-body" data-client-name="test1">
    <input class="gform_hidden" />
</div>
<div class="modal-body" data-client-name="new name">
    <input class="gform_hidden" />
</div>
<div class="modal-body" data-client-name="test3">
    <input class="gform_hidden" />
</div>
```

From there you can access this `data` attribute to fill the value of the `input`:

```
$('input.gform_hidden').val(function() {
    return $(this).closest('div').data('client-name');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://$('input.gform_hidden').val(function()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20return%20$(this).closest('div').data('client-name');%20%7D);)

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/9nph7eyc/10/), Any way you are getting the value of div attr, but you need to point out that particular input to print.

```
$('.modal-body').each(function() {
    var cname = $(this).attr('client-name');
    console.log(cname)
    $(this).find('.gform_hidden').val(cname);
});
```